# Sort patches by id

Tags: sorting, netlogo, patch

I know that patches are sorted with the top left-most patch first and the bottom right-most patch last. My question is: if patches have an id `patches-own[id]` is it possible to sort patches by id. I don't want a list but an agenset?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Alas, as noted here

> https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#agentsets

agentsets are always in random order.  As you likely know, however, you can make an ordered list of patches by id and then loop or map through it. The `sort-on` primitive will do that. As an example,

```
patches-own [ id ]
to test
  ask patches [set id random 10000]  ; assign random ids to patches
  let sorted-patches sort-on [id] patches
  show sorted-patches
  show map [[p] -> [id] of p] sorted-patches
end
```

gives you a sorted list of the patch ids.

Charles